# Uploading on AWS Glacier ; but Console doesnt show Inventory Last Updated or # of Archives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I was able to upload images using AWS Java SDK using ArchiveTransferManager.. The program ran through successfully; but when I check on AWS Console it still shows # of Archives as zero !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just takes time to show on AWS Console. I waited for few hours and it started showing up fine.

Comment: "The vault inventory is updated approximately once a day." http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/#data-inventories